# Difference between key (recv-keys), signing key, and fingerprint in APT/PPA system

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, deb

Let's take [ansible](https://launchpad.net/%7Eansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible) as an example. If you do click on the "Technical details about this PPA" link you see:

```
Signing key:
4096R/7BB9C367

Fingerprint:
6125E2A8C77F2818FB7BD15B93C4A3FD7BB9C367
```

If you try to add that software without adding the key you get

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't
be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 93C4A3FD7BB9C367
```

When I do `apt-key list` I see `4096R/7BB9C367`. To add the key I need to do:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367
```

And the fingerprint doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere. What is the difference between all these values?

Why do I not need to do `apt-key ... --recv-keys` if adding the PPA but I need to if manually adding the line to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? How does PPA know that `93C4A3FD7BB9C367` is what it needs to use, where does it find this?

**Bonus round**:

- What is the difference between using a PPA vs just adding a line to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?
- Where is this PPA thing 'hosted' that just adding `ppa:ansible/ansible` is enough to add that line to `sources.list.d`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll start with your last question.

`ppa:ansible/ansible` is a special format that refers to Launchpad PPAs and can be used in Ubuntu and Ubuntu derivatives (at least). In terms of functionality, a PPA is just a regular repo. However, this exact format can't just be added into `/etc/apt/sources.list`, since `apt` doesn't recognize this format. Therefore, the URL to the repo has to be added. For example, the URL for `ppa:teamName/archiveName` is `http://ppa.launchpad.net/teamName/archiveName/ubuntu`.

Typically, either Software Updater or the terminal is used to add a PPA. Software Updater recognizes the PPA syntax. In terminal, `apt-add-repository` recognizes the format and is typically used to add a PPA. This also gets the public key that is used to sign the repo. If, for some reason, it isn't able to, you'll get a similar warning that you got when running `sudo apt-get update`.

As for the fingerprint, the full fingerprint of a public-key is a 40-character alphanumeric representation of the public key. Launchpad shows the full 40 characters. However, typing or remembering 40 characters is difficult, especially when there are multiple public keys. Therefore, typically the last 8 or 16 characters are shown. `apt` is showing the last 16 characters of the fingerprint, and `apt-key list` (which uses `gpg` behind the scenes) is showing the last 8. The format to show in `gpg` can be configured.